# Custom URL on communities

Tags: community

We got a community which is being shared by a two different projects.

Landing page of community is different for two different projects

So as to make sure users land on correct pages,
custom urls on communities was suggested option (due to time restriction)

and when i try to create a custom url.i cannot publish it/test it..any idea what to do?

This is how i added custom url,
went to domain management--clicked add domain.gave a domain name

-Do i need to contact salesforce for enabling domain or something-

went to communities, selected force.com link ,next to  a particular community
selected custom url->create new
selected domain specified in previous step [Only those domains created by above steps can be selected here]

gave path as /name
and selected communinty for site[automatically populated]

Now i dont have a clue what to test/ how to make this url accessible

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can be done with SSL + Communities + Force.com Site + Branded Domain](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34623/what-can-be-done-with-ssl-communities-force-com-site-branded-domain)

Answer (score 6):

For Communities this is currently not supported, but an idea is posted on the Idea Exchange: [Private SSL url's for Force.com Sites](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006nxHAAQ)

Answer (score 0):

Custom URLs cannot be tested in the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

A recent (post-Summer 14) update now allows vanity domains for Communities.

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/api/release-notes/communities_custom_domain_URL.htm

Check out the Success Community for more information.

https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oDd&fId=0D53000001ZBmbJ&emtm=1407655656055&s1nid=0DB30000000072L&fromEmail=1&emkind=chatterGroupDigest&s1ext=0&s1oid=00D300000000iTz&s1uid=0053000000A8HTN