# Who to contact about enabling HTTPS custom domains for our organization?

Tags: force.com-sites

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/summer14/release-notes/communities_custom_domain_URL.htm

This page says that we must contact Salesforce, that's great but who in Salesforce do we contact?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can be done with SSL + Communities + Force.com Site + Branded Domain](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34623/what-can-be-done-with-ssl-communities-force-com-site-branded-domain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log a case through Help & Training > Contact Support.

Choose "CRM" from the "I need assistance with" dropdown, and then "Limits and Feature Activations" from Product Topics.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although the link says it is available, Support seems to disagree, even when I escalated it. No idea how to convince them otherwise.